# Generating samples according to arbitrary continous probability density

Tags: opencv, random, probability-density

I have a known probability density for a continuous random variable. How do I generate points that follow this probability density using OpenCV in C++? i.e I want to do what the RNG::uniform does, but for an arbitrary probability distribution.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, OpenCV has no functions for your task, but using RNG::uniform you can generate samples as you want, take a look at this paper: [paper](http://www.lattice.itep.ru/~pbaivid/lecture_notes/rejection_sampling.pdf).